# How to take MAX from two different columns from two different tables

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Table A, Table B, Table C and want to take MAX(OrderId) and group by from B and MAX(date) and group by from C

Table A:

```
SNO
AccNo
```

Table B:

```
SNO(FK)
OrderId
```

Table C:

```
AccNo(FK)
date
```

I have written something like this:

```
select b.max(OrderId), other columns
from a, b, c
where a.sno = b.sno
and a.accno = c.accno
and (b.orderid, c.date) IN (select b.orderid, max(c.date)
from a, b,c 
where a.sno = b.sno
and a.accno = c.accno
group by b.orderid)
group by other columns
```

Somehow this runs well but doesn't give the desired results. Would appreciate some help on it.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
select a.AccNo, max(b.orderId) as maxOrderId, max(myDate) as maxDate
from tableA a
inner join tableB b on a.SNO = b.SNO
inner join tableC c on a.AccNo = c.AccNo
group by a.AccNo
```

Is this what you wanted?